# Is df['A'] = df['A'] + df['B'] still a valid way to combine two columns of Text: SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've copied some columns over from an existing dataframe into a new dataframe like so:

```
df_1 = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['a','','c',''], 'B': ['','b','','d'], 'C': [1,2,3,4], 'D': [4,5,6,7]})

df_2 = df_1[['A', 'B']]
```

I'm combining two columns of text column A and column B and I'm getting SettingWithCopyWarning error by doing these operation:

```
df_2['A'] = df_2['A'] + df_2['B']
```

or

```
df_2['A'] = df_2['B'] + df_2['C']
```

I get this error with or without the column overwrite. I looked into the SettingWithCopyWarning and it only seems to become a problem when there is a double index such as df['A']['B'] = value. I wanted to double check and make sure that this type of thing was still ok to do. I created df_2 as a simplified version of df_1 and only intend to move forward with df_2. I want to preserve df_1 and not alter it.

```
df_1 = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['a','','c',''], 'B': ['','b','','d'], 'C': [1,2,3,4], 'D': [4,5,6,7]})

df_2 = df_1[['A', 'B']]

df_2['A'] = df_2['A'] + df_2['B']

df_2
```

I expect df['A'] should be ['a','b','c','d'] with df['B'] remaining ['','b','','d']

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.loc[]` or `copy()` to avoid this warning to create a "copy" and not a view:

```
df_1 = pandas.DataFrame({'A': ['a', '', 'c', ''], 'B': ['', 'b', '', 'd'],
                         'C': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'D': [4, 5, 6, 7]})

df_2 = df_1.loc[:, ['A', 'B']]  # <- HERE, or df_1['A', 'B'].copy()

df_2['A'] = df_2['A'] + df_2['B']
```

Output:

```
>>> df_2
   A  B
0  a   
1  b  b
2  c   
3  d  d
```

**More information**

```
# with df_2 = df_1[['A', 'B']]
>>> df_2._is_copy
<weakref at 0x7fd6cd9c94f0; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7fd7150c61c0>

>>> hex(id(df_1))
0x7fd7150c61c0

# with df_2 = df_1.loc[:, ['A', 'B']]
>>> None
```